# Authentication And Security for ASP. NET static files and folders

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have two domains both created in MVC.

1.User domain( Eg. `localhost:8000`)
2.Customer domain(Eg. `localhost:5046`)

Customer can login, then  he can upload files such as image, doc, pdf etc. The files get Uploaded to `~/Documents/` folder in the root directory of `localhost:5046`

The Problem: If I go to my browser and hit this URL `localhost:5046/Documents/image.jpg` I can actually access to file whether I have been authenticated or not.

What I need: I need to block the file access via the URL from browser. But I should be able to Access the file From the User domain `localhost:8000` by writing something like this below

```
WebClient Client = new WebClient();
resposeData = Client.DownloadData("localhost:5046/Documents/image.jpg");
```

Any idea and suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: what is there in your routeconfig, add that also?

Answer (score 1):

Authorize this in web config.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="pdfauthentication" verb="*"
        path="*.pdf"
        type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler"
        resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Now you can implement a handler pdfauthentication, where you have access to server url and can implement your own authentication logic. This solution is discussed [here](http://www.primaryobjects.com/2009/11/11/securing-pdf-files-in-asp-net-with-custom-http-handlers/)

Answer (score -1):

In the same scenario i perform follow checks
 
1.] It will return server address , if it is from Hosted serverthan redirect to another page with some message.

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
```

2.] Check if user is authenticated

```
 System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
```